# Hibernate is throwing JDBC Exception after 24 hours or so. Using MYSQL / Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

After 24 hour or so  of server start hibernate is throwing JDBCConnection Exception . I am using Hibernate / Mysql / Rest java project

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider</property>


    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">3000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>

</session-factory>
```

And I have created Hibernate Template class which is for Hibernate operations which look like this

```
public class HibernateTemplate {
private static final Logger logger =    Logger.getLogger(HibernateTemplate.class);

static SessionFactory factory = null;
private Session session = null;
private Transaction txn = null;

public Session getSession() {
    try {
        if (session == null || !session.isOpen()) {
            session = factory.openSession();
            txn = session.beginTransaction();
        }
    } catch (JDBCConnectionException e) {

        logger.error("JDBC Connection Exception   " + e.getStackTrace());

    }
    return session;
}

public HibernateTemplate() {
    if (factory == null || factory.isClosed()) {
        factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    }
    getSession();
}

private void postAction() {
    txn.commit();
}

private void postSession() {
    if (session.isOpen())
        session.close();

}

public Object get(Criteria cr) {
    Object responseEntity = null;
    getSession();

    try {
        responseEntity = cr.list();
        smsSent = false;
    } catch (JDBCConnectionException e) {
        logger.error("JDBC Connection Exception   " + e.getStackTrace());


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Exception while fetching data using Hibernate Template " + ex);
        return "error";
    } finally {
        // postAction();
        postSession();
    }

    return responseEntity;
}
}
```

This is bugging me alot

Comment: Usually, this kind of problem is caused by connections not being closed...

Comment: I would change `logger.error("JDBC Connection Exception   " + e.getStackTrace());` by `logger.error("JDBC Connection Exception.", e);` then edit this question and provide the stacktrace to analyze this problem

Comment: stacktrace says  : can not open a connection in getSession() method  after 24 hours.

Comment: is it because of I am keeping static sessionFactory ?

Answer (score 0):

It is common to see problems with connections that have been sitting idle in a connection pool for a long time before getting handed to the application for use. Most connection pools have configurations to control connection validation. You probably want to configure c3po to test the connection before giving it to your application. If it finds the connection is bad, it will handle the exception internally and you will not have to deal with it. The downside of turning this on is that there is an extra round-trip to the database, so it takes longer to get the connection from the connection pool.

You probably want to be using `testConnectionOnCheckout` rather than `idleConnectionTestPeriod` (which it appears that you may be using).

Quoting from http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing

> **Configuring Connection Testing**
>
> c3p0 can be configured to test the Connections that it pools in a
>   variety of ways, to minimize the likelihood that your application will
>   see broken or "stale" Connections. Pooled Connections can go bad for a
>   variety of reasons -- some JDBC drivers intentionally "time-out"
>   long-lasting database Connections; back-end databases or networks
>   sometimes go down "stranding" pooled Connections; and Connections can
>   simply become corrupted over time and use due to resource leaks,
>   driver bugs, or other causes.
>
> c3p0 provides users a great deal of flexibility in testing
>   Connections, via the following configuration parameters:
>
> - automaticTestTable
> - connectionTesterClassName
> - idleConnectionTestPeriod
> - preferredTestQuery
> - testConnectionOnCheckin
> - testConnectionOnCheckout
>
> idleConnectionTestPeriod, testConnectionOnCheckout, and
>   testConnectionOnCheckin control when Connections will be tested.
>   automaticTestTable, connectionTesterClassName, and preferredTestQuery
>   control how they will be tested.
>
> When configuring Connection testing, first try to minimize the cost of
>   each test. If you are using a JDBC driver that you are certain
>   supports the new(ish) jdbc4 API — and if you are using c3p0-0.9.5 or
>   higher! — let your driver handle this for you. jdbc4 Connections
>   include a method called isValid() that should be implemented as a
>   fast, reliable Connection test. By default, c3p0 will use that method
>   if it is present.
>
> However, if your driver does not support this new-ish API, c3p0's
>   default behavior is to test Connections by calling the getTables()
>   method on a Connection's associated DatabaseMetaData object. This has
>   the advantage of being very robust and working with any database,
>   regardless of the database schema. However, a call to
>   DatabaseMetaData.getTables() is often much slower than a simple
>   database query, and using this test may significantly impair your
>   pool's performance.
>
> The simplest way to speed up Connection testing under a JDBC 3 driver
>   (or a pre-0.9.5 version of c3p0) is to define a test query with the
>   preferredTestQuery parameter. Be careful, however. Setting
>   preferredTestQuery will lead to errors as Connection tests fail if the
>   query target table does not exist in your database prior to
>   initialization of your DataSource. Depending on your database and JDBC
>   driver, a table-independent query like SELECT 1 may (or may not) be
>   sufficient to verify the Connection. If a table-independent query is
>   not sufficient, instead of preferredTestQuery, you can set the
>   parameter automaticTestTable. Using the name you provide, c3p0 will
>   create an empty table, and make a simple query against it to test the
>   database.
>
> The most reliable time to test Connections is on check-out. But this
>   is also the most costly choice from a client-performance perspective.
>   Most applications should work quite reliably using a combination of
>   idleConnectionTestPeriod and testConnectionOnCheckin. Both the idle
>   test and the check-in test are performed asynchronously, which can
>   lead to better performance, both perceived and actual.
>
> For some applications, high performance is more important than the
>   risk of an occasional database exception. In its default
>   configuration, c3p0 does no Connection testing at all. Setting a
>   fairly long idleConnectionTestPeriod, and not testing on checkout and
>   check-in at all is an excellent, high-performance approach.